# MYSQL: How to use the result of a grouped SUM() as condition in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sum, where-clause

In my Table of TEAMS with relational table>rows for its PLAYERS

Each Team has 3 or more players
Each Player associated with the team has a points column

I need to retrieve only the TEAM w/c has accumulated player points of 300 or greater

I have gone to this point so far:

[image]

Problem with this is it returns a result set contain ALL the rows in the TEAMs table.

[image]

How do I make it return result only if SUM is > than , say, 300?

I tried adding:

```
**WHERE total_points >= '300'**
```

but obviously that returns an "unknown column" error.

Any ideas?

PS
I could easily get what i want via PHP > loop but it's such a waste on Server resource to be loading THOUSANDS of Team rows just to get a few that meets a criteria..

Comment: possible duplicate of [WHERE vs HAVING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having)

Comment: Also this one: [use mysql SUM() in a WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284409/use-mysql-sum-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the having clause .. it applies to groupings. (Similar to where)

so after the group put having sum(players.points)>300

Answer (score 1):

try using HAVING clause instead of WHERE

```
HAVING total_points >= 300
```