# SQL - using sum() to retrieve the first row where it gets to a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have this table, let's call it Lines:

```
id | id_sale | id_product | quantity
1      1           1           4
2      2           1           4
3      3           1           4
4      4           1           4
```

It represents the lines of a sale.

And I want to fetch the id of the line where the product gets sold X times. For something like this I believe that an order by id asc is needed.

For instance, with the previous data, for product 1 and to X = 6, I would get the id 2. Or for X = 10 I would get the id 3.

I have found a question that's pretty much what I need: 
[use mysql SUM() in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284409/use-mysql-sum-in-a-where-clause)

I have tried the correct answer (adapted for SQL) but in SQL I can't add the order by id inside the subquery, and because of this I believe the query stops making sense.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
select y.id, y.quantity 
from (select t.id, 
            t.quantity, 
            (select sum(x.quantity) 
                from Lines x
                where x.id <= t.id) as atmTotal
        from Lines t where t.id_product = 1) y
where y.atmTotal >= 10
order by y.ID;
```

Result: This is just returning all id's (and quantities) that have the product 1.

Comment: you are using sql-server as tagged correct?  You probably can use window functions to make this a little easier.  Your narative of your data doesn't match your example data (everything is quantity 4 in your table).  Can you edit to improve your sample data and provide a desired output example.

Comment: How do you get quantity 6 and 10?

Comment: Sorry, but I need to do this in a query.
But my data matches the narative.. (It doesn't matter if the quantity is always 4). I'll edited the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: So you want the ID of when the running total goes over X amount. The "Running Total" is key here and not well understood which is why I and Eric asked for clarification. Juan Carlos's answer is what I would have posted for that too unless you are using an rdbms that doesn't have window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/LYUK16627)**

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
        SELECT *,
               SUM([quantity]) OVER (ORDER BY [id]) as total // or ORDER [sales_id]
        FROM Lines
     ) T
WHERE total <= 6  // your X
ORDER BY total desc
```

Comment: I changed it to:

    select TOP 1 T.id_sale

    from (
     select *, sum([quantity]) over (order by [id]) as total from Lines
     where id_product = 4
     ) T
    where total >= 10
    order by total asc;

And it's just what I need, many thanks!

Comment: Ohh I see, glad you can fix it. I understand the problem upside down :P

Answer (score 0):

```
  select x.id ,sum(y.quantity) 
                    from Lines x,
                         Lines y
                where y.id <= x.id
    group by x.id
    having sum(y.quantity)  >= 10
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.