# Trying to get results based on another table - aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a single query that will select all users based on their sum of donation from another table and order by the sum of their donations. But I am getting an error. I'm using postgres but I guess the same would apply to mysqql.

```
ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 8:  sum(donations.donation) = 400
         ^
```

**users** table

```
id |   username   |
1     Larry Page
2     Sergey Brin
```

**donations** table

```
id | user_id | donation |     date
1      1         100       2019-02-12
2      1         200       2019-02-13
3      2         500       2019-01-15
4      1         100       2019-04-10
```

Here's my query

```
select
    users.username, sum(donations.donation) as donation_sum
from
    users
inner join donations
    on users.id = donations.user_id
where
    sum(donations.donation) = 400
and
    donations.date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
order by
    donation_sum
```

I was expecting the result to be this

```
username    |  donation_sum
Larry Page        400
```

Comment: Use `having` for filtering aggregated data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use mysql SUM() in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284409/use-mysql-sum-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter on aggregation results, you have to use the keyword `HAVING`:

```
select
    users.username, sum(donations.donation) as donation_sum
from
    users
inner join donations
    on users.id = donations.user_id
where
    donations.date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
group by
    users.username
having
    sum(donations.donation) = 400
order by
    donation_sum
```

Comment: . . . `Having` without `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Right, didn't even notice it was missing from the original query

Comment: . . .  Your current syntax still not valid.

Comment: Then answer the question yourself and please, politely annoy someone's else answer's comments

Comment: @YogeshSharma: you can fix obvious typos yourself by simply editing the answer

Comment: Which he did, changing all the formating in the same time, which is why I rolled it back.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using having, maybe with sub queries?

Comment: There, is, though they will be less efficient. Why do you wish so?